# return value from embedded c++ function in R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, inline-code

I've got some R code, that is somewhat slow, so I've been trying to write some c++ code directly in the R code using the 'inline' library.

This works well, and I'm now trying to tweak it.

I've only been able to make it work if I allocate the 'results' data structures in R and pass these as function parameters to the c function. I'm wondering if it is possible to have a non void c/c++ function in the R code, such that memory is allocated and returned from c/c++ and not R.

See example below:

```
library(inline)
cppSig <- signature(res="numeric",ary="numeric",len="integer")
cppBody <- "
int lens=len[0];
res[0]=0;
  for(int j=0;j<lens;j++)
     res[0] += ary[j];
res[0] /= (double) lens;
#if 0 //Is something like this possible? 
    double *rary = new double[lens];
    for(int i=0;i<lens;i++) rary[i] = ary[i]-res[0];
    return rary;
#endif
"
cfun <- cfunction( sig=list(myMean=cppSig), 
                 body=list(cppBody),verbose=T, 
                 convention=".C", cxxargs="-O3", cppargs="-O3",language="C++")
cfunWrap <- function(x)
  cfun$myMean(res=0,ary=x,length(x))$res


cfunWrap(x=rnorm(100))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things I'd do differently, particularly after even just a *casual glance* at the Rcpp documentation. So here is just a quick list:

1. Yes, we can make loops faster. Often by a lot.
2. Yes, we can return atomic C/C++ types as well as vectors. There are lots of example. One uses `wrap()` for these non-vector types; vectors of double are returned automatically. But you **never ever** use `new`/`delete` on them. See `Writing R Extensions` for why.
3. Yes, you can use the inline package. And we use it a lot. But we **never** use it with the `.C()` call convention from the `cfunction()`. **Always** use `cxxfunction()`, or at least enable `.Call()`. I am not sure how you missed that.
4. Since Rcpp 0.10.0, we have 'Rcpp Attributes' which are even easier to use than inline and its `cxxfunction()`.  Look around for example for `sourceCpp()` or `cppFunction()`, or even read the vignette.
5. Lastly, you are really missing some elementary stuff. Did you read the pdf vignettes Rcpp-iintroduction and/or Rcpp-FAQ?

*Edit:*  Okay, here is a full example following the structure of your function (but we can do better, see below for that):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp; 

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector monkey(NumericVector ary) {
  int lens = ary.length();   // objects can tell you about their length
  double res=0;
  for(int j=0;j<lens;j++) res += ary[j];
  res /= (double) lens;

  NumericVector rary(lens);
  for(int i=0;i<lens;i++) rary[i] = ary[i]-res;
  return rary;
}

// and we even include some R code to test automagically

/*** R
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(5)   # just five to keep printout short
monkey(x)
cat("Check:")
x - mean(x)
*/
```

which, if you call it, also runs the R code at the bottom:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp('/tmp/monkey.cpp')

R> set.seed(42)

R> x <- rnorm(5)   # just five to keep printout short

R> monkey(x)
[1]  0.9296545 -1.0060021 -0.0781755  0.1915587 -0.0370356

R> cat("Check:")
Check:
R> x - mean(x)
[1]  0.9296545 -1.0060021 -0.0781755  0.1915587 -0.0370356
R>
```

But one of the **key features of Rcpp** is that you can even do the vector operation in C++:

```
R> cppFunction('NumericVector monkey2(NumericVector x) { return x - mean(x); }')
R> monkey2(x)
[1]  0.9296545 -1.0060021 -0.0781755  0.1915587 -0.0370356
R>
```

That just compiled a new one-line C++ function which operated *on the whole vector `x`* and ran it.

Comment: Dirk, your point 3 seems a bit harsh given that `?cfunction` actually has an example of using `.C` with `cfunction`....

Comment: @HongOoi: You can use `cfunction()` with `.Call()`, and should. But you simple **cannot use Rcpp with the limited `.C()` interface**. For `SEXP` interchange you must use `.Call()`, not `.C()`.  The inline package started before Rcpp.  We only use the `cxxfunction()` extension (or in older examples `cfunction()` with the `.Call()` interface called explicitly). There is simply no other way.

Comment: @HongOoi: I reworded that point a little; hope it is clearer now. `cfunction()` can use (though `cxxfunction()` sets more arguments right) but you *must* use the `.Call()` interface.  Or just use 'Rcpp Attributes'.